# implementing a infixToPostfix method, but don't know why do I push '(' at first time

Tags: c, data-structures, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I didn't implement whole infixTopostFix method yet.
but I have a question about it.
I am figuring out it still.

(notice: My infixToPostfix method is not complete yet)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

int top = -1;
char stack[SIZE];
void push(char data){

  if(top > SIZE-1)
    printf("full size\n");
  else{
    top = top + 1;
    stack[top] = data;
  }
}

char pop(){
  char data;
  if(top<0)
    printf("pop: empty!\n");
  else{
    data = stack[top--];
    return data;
  }
}

int is_operator(char symbol){

if(symbol == '^' || symbol == '*' || symbol == '/' || symbol == '+' || symbol == '-' || symbol == '')
  return 1;
else
  return 0'

}

int precedence(char symbol){
  if(symbol == '^'){
    return 3;
  }else if(symbol == '*' || symbol == '/'){
    return 2;
  }else if(symbol == '-' || symbol == ''){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

So now, there's a inFixToPostfix method.

```
int infixToPostfix(char exp[], char postix[]){
  int i, j;
  char data;
  char x;
```

and my question is about this part.
this push method(below) has a parameter '('. and this is the first parameter of push.
but I don't get it why should I push this first.

I mean.. I can see this code means ( expression here ).
but I would think just an expression without parenthesis.

```
  push('(');
  strcat(exp, ')');

  i = 0; j = 0;
  data = exp[i];

  while(data != NULL){
    if(data == '('){
      push(data);
    }
    else if( isdigit(data) || isalpha(data)){
      postfix[j] = data;
      j++;
    }
    else if(is_operator(data) == 1){
      x = pop();

    }
  }
}

int main(void) {

  char exp[] = "(a+b)*3+(c-d)*2";
  char postfix[SIZE];
  // postfix: ab3+*cd2-*
  infixToPostfix(exp, postfix);
  puts(postfix);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that any mathematical expression evaluates to the same value as that expression surrounded by parentheses. We take advantage of this property by marking the beginning of the expression being parsed with a `'('`. This allows the algorithm to evaluate the final value without using a special case. I suggest after you get it working, remove the line that pushes the paren and step through your code with an example input. This exercise will help you understand its purpose.